# Local image displays in IE but not firefox?

Tags: html, firefox, image

I have the following line to display an image:

```
$output .= '<div><img src="C:/backup/images/000001_full.jpg"></div>';
```

($output is then put into an html file as a local backup). When I view the page with IE, the image is displayed fine, but not with firefox. 
Any idea why?

Thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want:

`$output .= '<div><img src="file://c:/backup/images/000001_full.jpg"></div>';`

Answer (score 1):

You need to close your img tag. So,

```
$output .= '<div><img src="C:/backup/images/000001_full.jpg" /></div>';
```

IE likes to play it kind of loose with HTML specs, but Firefox pays more attention to the standards.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because your src is not valid urlfor Firefox.
Have you tried `file://c:/backup/images/000001_full.jpg` ?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a link to the file system location? 
The image should be part of the site, and should be linked to as a relative URL such as \images\000001_full.jpg.

Comment: its to make a local backup of the site. Notice how the image is in C:/backup

Answer (score 0):

use relative path. i am also not sure but Something like  `$output .= '<div><img src="../images/000001_full.jpg"/></div>'`

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced this problem. The image displays in IE (and Chrome), but not in Firefox. The reason is because local files can't be accessed directly. Prefix the `src` tag with `file:///` and it will work just fine as in:

```
$output .= '<div><img src="file:///C:/backup/images/000001_full.jpg"></div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not straight forward in Chrome and firefox.
Modern browsers due to security reasons do not allow you to show image from file system.

Steps:
 1. set variable where your input type file is defined

```
HTML : <input type="file" id="image-input"/>
var fileInput = document.getElementById('image-input');
```

2. Get temporary file URI:

   var uri = window.URL.createObjectURL(fileInput.files[0]);
   Pass this Uri to the image src from Javascript. Problem solved.

Follow this link for help:
http://www.philliphaydon.com/2014/04/loading-an-image-or-video-from-a-file-input-control/